# jq : continue parsing ignoring invalid literals

Tags: json, bash, error-handling, try-catch, jq

I am using the streaming capability of jq to parse JSON from a large compressed file. The JSON I am receiving is not a faulty one, and I have verified it a few times. Upon parsing the compressed files after certain lines , I keep on getting the error such as :

```
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 3524768, column 0
```

I verified the line 3524768, and it shows a perfectly fine JSON.

```
{"created_at":"Mon Jul 18 08:02:46 +0000 2016","id":754949520631496704,"id_str":"754949520631496704","text":"je regarde le monde de charlotte et si je le finis t\u00f4t je regarde Caroline","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":2760400101,"id_str":"2760400101","name":"m.d.r","screen_name":"eoalfd","location":"nevers","url":null,"description":"emmenez-moi voir odezenne | hugo&mel","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":683,"friends_count":262,"listed_count":15,"favourites_count":6493,"statuses_count":42605,"created_at":"Wed Sep 03 14:55:50 +0000 2014","utc_offset":-25200,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"fr","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"F5ABB5","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/753684703450923008\/U-11Brew_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/753684703450923008\/U-11Brew_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/2760400101\/1468624180","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"fr","timestamp_ms":"1468828966659"}
```

The filter I am applying(which works for except this particular line ) goes as :

```
jq '. as $parent |.text | match("#(?!(p[0-9])|([0-9])|(q[0-9]|_))[a-zA-Z0-9]+") as $result | {"time":$parent.timestamp_ms,"string":$result.string}'
```

Infact when I just extract the line 3524768 to an isolated file and run my jq parser, it works perfectly fine! Is there any way I can make my jq parser running despite this numeric literal error? Maybe, ignoring it and carry on with the next line? 
I have been stuck in this for a couple of days, any help would be great.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem - using the line in your question and `.user.name` I extacted `"m.d.r"`. See https://jqplay.org/s/6wKcHE5_WA.

Comment: @JackFleeting. I am trying to apply a more complicated filter , such as : 
. as $parent |.text | match("#(?!(p[0-9])|([0-9])|(q[0-9]|_))[a-zA-Z0-9]+") as $result | {"time":$parent.timestamp_ms,"string":$result.string}'

Comment: What's your expected output from that complicated filter?

Comment: @JackFleeting
I'm getting texts with hashtags from the filter. Which is working fine, except on this one line which throws its off

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the line number in the error message is off by one.

In any case, to recover from an error, you can use the idiom illustrated by the following:

```
def process:
  try (inputs | type) 
  catch ("error at line \(input_line_number)", process);

process
```

With a program like this, you would normally invoke jq with the -n command-line argument.

### Example

Using your filter, you could write:

```
def myfilter:
  . as $parent 
  | .text
  | match("#(?!(p[0-9])|([0-9])|(q[0-9]|_))[a-zA-Z0-9]+") as $result
  | {"time":$parent.timestamp_ms,"string":$result.string} ;

def process:
  try (inputs | myfilter) 
  catch ("error at line \(input_line_number)", process);

process
```

Comment: How can i print the error  statement at that line , and keep continuing to the next line applying the same filter. Right now , the program just stops at the error point saying error at line , and doesnt carry forward

Comment: Have you tried the program shown in the Example section? It should help pinpoint the problem and will attempt to recover after each error is encountered.

Comment: Yes , I did try the program you showed in the example section. it emits the error , but doesn't proceed forward . I tried it multiple times as well.

Comment: Why don’t you try a simpler myfilter and pinpoint the point of failure more precisely.